# Best way to wait for two async firebase ml vision method results to use them in a third method

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-mlkit

When using firebase ml vision to recognize qr codes and/or text from an image. What is the best way to wait for the async text and barcode detector methods to resolve so I can utilize their results in a third method.

I am aware than I can call an alternative method from each async methods "onsuccess" listener to set a "hasReturned" variable and only proceed once both methods have returned but I am looking for the proper way to do this.

```
private void firebaseRecognitionFromImage(FirebaseVisionImage image) {

    //detect qr code
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS).build();
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector qrDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);
    qrDetector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) { /* RESULT 1 */ }
    });

    //detect text
    FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer textDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
    textDetector.processImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText texts) { /* RESULT 2 */ }
    });

    //process qr code and text information or lack thereof
    thirdMedthod("RESULT 1", "RESULT 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the variants of [`Tasks.whenAll()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)).  It will create a new Task object that completes when other tasks complete.

```
Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> t1 = qrDetector.detectInImage(image);
Task<FirebaseVisionText> t2 = textDetector.processImage(image);
Tasks.whenAll(t1, t2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    // check the results of t1 and t2
});
```

Learn more about [Play Services Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) in [this blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).